# Meaning of bet on something

Tags: meaning

Hassan Rouhani, **who bet his presidency on the deal** — only to be repudiated by Mr. Trump — cannot stand in a third consecutive election.

What is the meaning of the bold part in the above sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

betting on something, means to place a wager on something, when you are so certain that something will happen, you place a wager on it.
Here it means that the wager was his presidency, meaning that if the deal don't take place he is willing to lose his presidency.